# Unexpected JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH error with removeChild

Tags: google-closure-compiler

When I compile the following code

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @formatting pretty_print
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
let source;
function v() {
  const me = document.createElement('div');

  function setSource() {
    if (source) {
      me.removeChild(source); // line 8
      source = undefined;
    }
    source = document.createElement('div');
  }
}
```

at the online closure compiler, https://closure-compiler.appspot.com I get the following error:

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of Node.prototype.removeChild does not match formal parameter
found   : (Element|undefined)
required: (Node|null) at line 8 character 23
        me.removeChild(source);
```

What I'm expecting to happen is that it will infer that `source` cannot be undefined at line 8, and so not complain about the call to `removeChild()`. Indeed, in some simpler examples, that's what it appears to do.

The type of `source` is certainly `(Element|undefined)` outside the conditional, so maybe it's just not intended to work?

I'm wondering if I should file a bug report.

The online compiler says this code doesn't compile, but maybe it interprets zero output together with non-zero warnings as an error? This example was distilled from some code which had actual side effects and did compile successfully.

**Update:** This is working as intended: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/2382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the type of `source` and it works.  This [compiles with the online compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257BElement%257Cundefined%257D%2520*%252F%250Alet%2520source%253B%250Afunction%2520v()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520const%2520me%2520%253D%2520document.createElement('div')%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520function%2520setSource()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(source)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520me.removeChild(source)%253B%2520%252F%252F%2520line%25208%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520source%2520%253D%2520undefined%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520source%2520%253D%2520document.createElement('div')%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D).

```
/** @type {Element|undefined} */
let source;
function v() {
  const me = document.createElement('div');

  function setSource() {
    if (source) {
      me.removeChild(source); // line 8
      source = undefined;
    }
    source = document.createElement('div');
  }
}
```

But you might be correct that this is a compiler bug. If the compiler guesses that `source` has type `{Element|undefined}` then it should infer that `source` is type `{Element}` on line 8.

However it's usually better to tell the compiler what the types of things are when you know them.  Otherwise the compiler has to guess, and perhaps the guess about the type isn't happening early enough in the compilation process, hence you get this kind of "bug".

Speculation: without the type annotation the compiler is guessing the type of `source` by looking at the other code that assigns to `source`.  Since `document.createElement` returns `Element` and another line of code assigns `source = undefined` the guess that the type of source is `{Element|undefined}` is reasonable.